# Removing specific notification when you don't know the notification id?

Tags: android, push-notification

How can I remove a specific notification when I don't know the notification id (when app was not running and OS generated the notifications)? I don't want to use `notificationManager.cancelAll()` because there are multiple types of notifications and I can't use `notificationManager.cancel(id)` because I don't know the ID of that notification.

I've already gone through most of the SO threads so please don't mark it as a duplicate of the following:

[How to clear a notification in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665634/how-to-clear-a-notification-in-android)

[How to remove an android push notification from notification center when the app gets started by its launcher icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019547/how-to-remove-an-android-push-notification-from-notification-center-when-the-app/33735457#33735457)

[How to remove push notifications that have already been sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817182/how-to-remove-push-notifications-that-have-already-been-sent)

[How to remove an android push notification from notification center when the app gets started by its launcher icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019547/how-to-remove-an-android-push-notification-from-notification-center-when-the-app)

Comment: When creating some notifications you can create notifications by different channels and then it will be easier for you to remove them.

Comment: but I'm not creating the notifications @SubhasmithThapa , OS is. My app is killed.

Comment: What kind of notifications are they creating? Can you show?

Comment: Simple push notifications through firebase.